# How to map a Class to multiple databases in sqlalchemy orm

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using a sqlite database as my application file through sqlalchemy. I have a separate configuration file.

There are some classes whose information I persist on my application file that I would like to replicate on my configuration file. The thing is that I would load it alternatively from one or the other source depending on availability.

I saw this mention on the documentation, but I think it does not directly apply as the secondary mapping will not not persist the information. Also, the notion of which would be the primary is blurry. Both databases would carry the same information, maybe not on the same version, though.
http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#multiple-mappers-for-one-class

I will try to make it clearer with an example:

I have a class A which represents a multi-field user input. I save this on my application file.

A class B also on my application file file is composed of an instance of Class A.

The same instance from Class A may compose several suitable instances of Class B. These are all stored on my application file.

My problem is that on another session, with a brand new configuration file I might want to reuse that Class A instance. I can not have it only on the application file, because if it gets updated, it will be relevant across all application files that use it.

On the other hand, it can not be only in the configuration file, as a user might share his application file with another and the later might not have a suitable configuration and would have to do it manually.

I need to have it in both places, be able to choose which database will be the source at runtime and have all changes persist on both databases at once.

Can it be done in sqlalchemy+sqlite? Is it a good idea? Are there classic solutions for this?

EDIT:
I think I am describing something that looks like a cache, which sqlalchemy does not do. Does any other approach come to mind?
Does sqlalchemy allow me to map an instance to a database upon instance creation? This would allow for two instances of the same class to be mapped against different databases. Then I would listen for an update event by sqlalchemy and issue the same sql to the other database. I also do not know how to do this.

Another option: map my class against a union query. Sqlalchemy might allow as it does for arbitrary selects, BUT then there is the persistence issue.

Another option: add a layer to the engine so that it connects to two databases simultaneously, issuing the same commands to both for reading and writing. I could deal with the duplicated returns.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the mixin below. I does not handle expunge or rollback, as I do not use those in my application nor know how to get about them.
It looks like it is working. I will proceed to expand it to handle collections.

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, String, Enum, Integer, event
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

class ReplicateMixin:
    @classmethod
    def get_or_create(cls,prime_session, sessoes = None, **kwargs):
        if sessoes is None:
            sessoes = []
        if not isinstance(sessoes, list):
            sessoes = [sessoes]
        sessoes = [prime_session] + sessoes #They are passed separatelly just to make explicit that the first might receive diferent treatment
        replicas = []

        for sessao in sessoes: #Gets a result or creates a new instance from each database
            instance = sessao.query(Datum).filter_by(**kwargs).first()
            if instance is None: 
                instance = cls(**kwargs)
                setattr(instance, "__new", True)
            sessao.add(instance) 
            instance.sessao = sessao
            replicas.append(instance)

        fittest = cls.__select_fittest(replicas) #Selects the instance whose data will prevail 
        prime = replicas.pop(0) #Instance from the session we will be issuing commits to. The others must simply follow.
        cls.__copy_data(fittest, prime, ReplicateMixin.__get_primary_keys(prime))

        setattr(prime, "__replicas", replicas) #The object will carry references to its copies
        return prime

    @staticmethod
    def __select_fittest(instances):
        """This method should contain logic for choosing the instance that has
        the most relevant information. It may be altered by child classes"""
        if getattr(instances[0], "__new", False):
            return instances[1]
        else:
            return instances[0] 

    @staticmethod
    def __copy_data(source, dest, primary_keys = None):
        primary_keys = [] if primary_keys is None else primary_keys
        for prop in orm.class_mapper(type(source)).iterate_properties:
            if (isinstance(prop, orm.ColumnProperty)
                and prop.key not in primary_keys):
                setattr(dest, prop.key,
                        getattr(source, prop.key))

    @staticmethod
    def __replicate(mapper, connection, original_obj):
        replicants = getattr(original_obj, "__replicas", []) #if it IS a replicant it will not have a __replicas attribute
        primary_keys = ReplicateMixin.__get_primary_keys(original_obj)
        for objeto in replicants:
            ReplicateMixin.__copy_data(original_obj, objeto, primary_keys)
            objeto.sessao.commit()

    @staticmethod
    def __replicate_del(mapper, conection, original_obj):
        replicants = getattr(original_obj, "__replicas", []) #if it IS a replicant it will not have a __replicas attribute
        for objeto in replicants:
            if objeto in objeto.sessao.new:
                objeto.sessao.expunge(objeto)
            else:
                objeto.sessao.delete(objeto)
            objeto.sessao.commit()

    @staticmethod
    def __get_primary_keys(mapped_object):
        return [key.name for key in orm.class_mapper(type(mapped_object)).primary_key]

    @classmethod
    def __declare_last__(cls):
        """Binds certain events to functions"""
        event.listen(cls, "before_insert", cls.__replicate)
        event.listen(cls, "before_update", cls.__replicate)
        event.listen(cls, "before_delete", cls.__replicate_del)
        #FIXME might not play well with rollback
```

Example:

```
DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()
class Datum (ReplicateMixin, DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "xUnitTestData"
    Key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Value = Column(Float)
    nome = Column(String(10))
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}; {}; {}".format(self.Key, self.Value, self.nome)




end_local = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "local.bd")
end_remoto = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "remoto.bd")
src_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+end_local, echo=False)
dst_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+end_remoto, echo=False)
DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(src_engine)
DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(dst_engine)
SessionSRC = sessionmaker(bind=src_engine)
SessionDST = sessionmaker(bind=dst_engine)


session1 = SessionSRC()
session2 = SessionDST()

item = Datum.pegar_ou_criar(session1, session2, Value = 0.5, nome = "terceiro")

item.Value = item.Value/2
print(item)
session1.delete(item)

session1.commit()
session1.close()
```